# How to Reduce the Size or Bridge the Gap of a Vinyl Floor Expansion Gap

Tags: bathroom, flooring, vinyl-flooring

Our new vinyl floor in our bathroom required a 3/8" gap next to all vertical surfaces for room to expand. Ours ended up being a bit larger than that and we are trying to find out what we can do to reduce the gap (or bridge it) without redoing the floor. We want to use rubber trim like the one below, but it won't cover the gap.

We placed the rubber trim in and for the most part the gaps don't show. Where they do show we filled the holes with a gray silicone. It's not the ideal solution but it works and isn't noticeable.

[image: Gap between floor and wall]
[image: Gap between floor and tub]
[image: Rubber base trim]

Comment: How big is the bathroom, and does the floor go out into a hallway or larger area?

Comment: The bathroom is quite small. Only about 8'x5'.

Answer (score 1):

Use a traditional baseboard. If you're concerned about moisture, instead of wood/particle board, get PVC. There is plenty of nice stuff available like [this one from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Royal-Mouldings-Creation-Series-6614-9-16-in-x-2-1-4-in-x-84-in-PVC-Composite-White-Colonial-Casing-Moulding-0661407003/202089988)

[image]

You should be able to find one with a just-wide-enough base. If not, use something simpler and add a matching 1/4-round.

You can paint the baseboard the same color as your walls or a contrasting color.

Comment: We're considering this, but right now we're still trying to find a way to use the rubber baseboard. We're thinking of possibly filling the gaps with gray silicone, but we're not sure if that will interfere with the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Nail a shim of wood or drywall the proper thickness along the base of the wall. Attach a strip of beveled wood (or coving) along the top of the baseboard so that is close to flush when the vinyl is attached. Attach the vinyl to the baseboard. Use joint compound to eliminate any seams. Sand the dried joint compound to make a smooth surface. Paint with a clear epoxy sealant to make the top of the baseboard waterproof. Paint again with a second coat of the desired wall color. Optionally, you can apply another clear coat of epoxy over the color coat to increase moisture resistance.